# DesignIntf not found in bpi but works with dcp

Tags: c++builder, vcl

In Rad Studio Rio, I create a package for Delphi.
In the PAS unit, I add:

```
  uses DesignIntf;
```

The compiler complains about "DesignIntf not found". Adding DesignIntf.dcp as reference solves the problem.

Now, if I create the same package but from C++ Builder, I add "uses DesignIntf;" in the PAS unit, if I add DesignIntf.bpi as reference, the error is not fixed.

Why in Delphi  DesignIntf.dcp solves the problem but DesignInt.bpi does not solve it for C++Builder with exactly the same code?

**UPDATE;**

It is win32 platform. The following image shows how designintf.bpi is referenced but I continue getting the error. It works as expected if the package is for Delphi and using designintf.dcp.

[image]

Comment: COuld it be you are using win64 platform, or any other than win32? - in that case DesignIntf is NOT available.

Comment: It is win32, you can see it in the above screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In both Delphi and C++, your design-time package needs a reference to the `DesignIDE` package in order to use the `DesignIntf` unit.

Please read Embarcadero's documentation:

[Compiling C++ Design-Time Packages That Contain Delphi Source](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiling_C%2B%2B_Design-Time_Packages_That_Contain_Delphi_Source)

[Creating or Extending a Package to Use the Tools API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_or_Extending_a_Package_to_Use_the_Tools_API)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved it.  I missed to add **-LUDesignIDE** under Delphi Compiler options. It is explained at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Compiling_C%2B%2B_Design-Time_Packages_That_Contain_Delphi_Source

The reason is because I mix Delphi and C++ code.